# python list error:IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, macos, apple-m1

I am trying to make a script that will help me build things in minecraft.
It has never worked.
i need help with it.
I don't know what to try.
python file that is giving me errors:

https://pastebin.com/Q9Vm4yfk

test.ch&bpy:

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

errors:

```
(env) me@some-mac qrctochbqr % python3 /Users/myname/env/qrctochbqr/buildtest.py
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/Users/myname/env/qrctochbqr/buildtest.py", line 48, in run
        print(self.irtbb[self.wv1])
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "string index out of range" simply means that you're trying to fetch an element from a position that doesn't exist. For example, if you have a string

str = "Hello World",

and you are trying to fetch the character indexed 100 out of that string:

char = str[100],

you will of course run into a problem, since your string doesn't have 100 characters. So, go check why the index you're trying to fetch doesn't exist.